Ошибка AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'
Есть готовый тгбот парсер погоды и вот в чём загвоздка, он работает но через раз, то есть из 10 попыток запуска, он сработает 7-8 раз и это как то странно (то есть всё работает, потом через время ты опять включаешь бота и бац ошибка). Вопрос что делать? А ещё как можно было бы сократить ссылку сайта для парсингу
temp = soup.find('span', class_='wob_tq8U8x').text
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'text'**
import requests
import fake_useragent
import telebot
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

KEY = '###'
bot = telebot.TeleBot(KEY)

user = fake_useragent.UserAgent().random
header = {'user-agent': user}
url = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0+%D0%BD%D0%B0+%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B2%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0+%D0%B2+%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5&sca_esv=3e5381c58a31f6c2&sxsrf=ADLYWIKygL6UL-lLKvMvT-ytyoThuW2U3w%3A1724232659733&ei=07PFZtOvLPbRwPAPo6-ggQM&oq=%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0&gs_lp=Egxnd3Mtd2l6LXNlcnAiDNC_0L7Qs9C-0LTQsCoCCAEyBxAjGLADGCcyBxAjGLADGCcyBxAjGLADGCcyChAAGLADGNYEGEcyChAAGLADGNYEGEcyChAAGLADGNYEGEcyChAAGLADGNYEGEcyChAAGLADGNYEGEcyChAAGLADGNYEGEcyChAAGLADGNYEGEdIowxQAFgAcAF4AZABAJgBAKABAKoBALgBAcgBAJgCAaACC5gDAIgGAZAGCpIHATGgBwA&sclient=gws-wiz-serp'
response = requests.get(url, headers=header).text
soup = BeautifulSoup(response, 'lxml')


temp = soup.find('span', class_='wob_t q8U8x').text
day = soup.find('span', id='wob_dc').text.lower()
weather_day = soup.find('span', id='wob_ws').text
block_weather = soup.find('div', class_='wtsRwe')
full1_weather = block_weather.find('span', id='wob_hm').text


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def hello(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Что бы узнать погоду в Краснодаре пропишите "/pogoda"')


@bot.message_handler(commands=['pogoda'])
def weather(message):
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, f'Завтра в краснодаре {temp}°C,  а также {day},  ветер {weather_day}, влажность {full1_weather}')


bot.polling(none_stop=True)


Приведите полный стек-трейс ошибки прямо в вопросе.

Проверяйте статус запроса.

По тексту ошибки понятно, что вы пытаетесь взять свойство text у None. То есть что-то - это None. Скорее всего, вам выдают какой-то неправильный ответ. Поймайте ошибку и узнайте, чем неправильный ответ отличается от правильного.
